# Is there a Possibility to Configure Visual Studio Formatting to ignore whitespaces around variable assignments

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autoformatting

I have variables Assigned like this, so all assignment operators are in line.

```
var filterSets      = ...;
var names           = ...;
var filter          = ...;
```

when Visual Studio formatted it. (for Example when reapplying the last })

```
var filterSets = ...;
var names = ...;
var filter = ...;
```

Whats also applying a change for those 3 lines;

I searched a while and didn't find a way to configure the Formatting to ignore those whitespaces.

I wouldn't really care if it wouldn't show as changes in version Control...

Comment: To me second snippet is more readable. A matter of habit I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't mention which VS version you are using, however, in VS 2017 you can find this in Tools/Options, under Text Editor/C#/Code Style/Formatting/Spacing.

The option is called "Ignore spaces in declaration statements"

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I missed that. It Solves half of the changes, sadly it only affects declarations, Assignments like a property or a Global will still be changed. But I dont' think there are more options.